# Get value form same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have dropdown menu with 3 values.

[image]

and here is my table (table name is Sms)

[image]

What I want to do? Example : If I choose 2,49 and press submit, then I get `sonum` value.

This is my form

```
<div class="col_12" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <div class="col_6"> 
                <label for="asukoht">Vali Hind</label>
                <form class="vertical" method="GET">
                    <select name="hind">
                    <option value="1">-- Vali --</option>
                    <?php
                        
                    // Tegin dropdown menüü, kust saab valida komponendi, mille alla see pilt läheb
                    $andmed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sms");
                     
                     // Dropdown menüü
                    while($rida = mysql_fetch_array($andmed)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$rida['id'] . '">'.utf8_encode($rida['hind'] ). '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add">
                </form>
```

I tried something like this

```
if(mysql_query("DESCRIBE `Sms`")) {
                    
                        $sql = "SELECT sonum FROM `Sms`";
                    echo $sql;
}
```

I think it should be pretty easy, but I'm looking for a solution and I didnt found it.

Thank you for helping !

Comment: its maybe easier to do with jquery, but im not good with this .

Comment: $sql = "SELECT sonum FROM `Sms` WHERE id = ".$_GET['hind'];

Comment: @Marco Nice ! But I got `Resource id #7` if I echoed this.

Comment: You need to fetch the data OP. mysql_fetch_row (example). Better for you to use mysqli or pdo, mysql_* are deprecated and not supported anymore

Comment: Thanks Marco ! Can u put your answer in to answers, or I accept some other answer ?

Comment: i think you can accept joci93 answer (example)

Comment: yea , but this not work correctly, there is missing $andmed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sms");

                    while($rida = mysql_fetch_array($andmed)){

Comment: Maybe u post your answer here and I can accept this. You deserve it

Comment: op, it will be better to use $_GET only after cheking it ;) remember this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work on SQL and Loop.

Based on your code:

```
if(mysql_query("DESCRIBE `Sms`")) {

                        $sql = "SELECT sonum FROM `Sms`";
                    echo $sql;
}
```

First we do change the query including $_GET parameter.
So this:

```
$sql = "SELECT sonum FROM `Sms`";
```

Will become:

```
$sql = "SELECT sonum FROM `Sms` WHERE id = ".$_GET['hind'];
```

It will be better if you check that the var exist and is setted with something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['hind']) && is_numeric(trim($_GET['hind']){//Code here}
```

But it is off-topic.
Now let's change `echo $sql;` with a loop, we need to loop and fetch the data.

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo '<option value="'.$result ['id'] . '">'.utf8_encode($result ['hind'] ). '</option>';
}
```

I've only changed what i know, you know your system ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
    $sql = "SELECT sonum FROM Sms WHERE id = ".$_GET['hind'];
```

Then do :

```
    echo mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT sonum FROM Sms WHERE id = ".$_GET['hind'];
while($rida = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<option value="'.$rida['id'] . '">'.utf8_encode($rida['hind'] ). '</option>';
}
```

Do not use MYSQL queries...try MySQLi or PDO with prepared statement.